# How to run in low resolution 640x480

Tags: 14.04, monitor, settings, display-resolution, tv

I need to reduce the resolution to 640x480 to connect to my tv that can detect only that resolution.Any idea on how to do it so that my laptop screen resolution doesn't get affected? Ubuntu 14.04 can't seem to go below/detect a lower resolution for output.

Answer (score 0):

- GUI way is to open System Settings -> Displays
- command-line way: run `xrandr` command to find out available resolutions  per display. Choose the one you want changed, run `xrand --output $DISPLAY --mode $ZZZx$YYY`

  ---

Example:

Changing eDP1 to 6840x480

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 2390 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1366x768+1024+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 345mm x 194mm
   1366x768       60.0*+
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA1 connected primary 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)

$ xrandr --output eDP1 --mode 640x480
```